# Hornetq performance issue

Tags: hornetq

I tested the massaging speed of hornetq-2.0.0GA and hornetq- 2.2.5 Final and found that messaging speed is higher for older version, is it true or my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell. It will all depend on what test you're doing...

You need to make sure you're doing proper syncs, and scaling up your test. The server will sometimes need to make sure the semantics of transactions are preserved and you may get the feeling that one producer is slower, but you need to make a proper test to measure this.

This thread of yours is actually a good candidate as being closed, as the question doesn't state what you're doing.